# Is C# Cross Platform or not?

Tags: c#, cross-platform

I've been asking myself a lot lately what programming language to learn and often came up with C#, however I want my projects to be Cross Platform means I can use them Windows,Linux but also macOS.
Therefore here is the question:
Is C# Cross Platform or not? Because many say yes it is Cross Platform but some also say it is only for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the c# application can be compiled on windows only, but some can be a cross platform.

- .NET Framework: For **Windows** only
- .NET Core: Cross platform

**Applications available for C#:**

- **Console Application:** Cross platform
- **Windows Form Application:** For Windows Only
- **Windows Presentation Foundation(WPF):** For Windows Only
- **ASP.NET:** Cross platform
- **Blazor:** Cross platform

Answer (score -1):

C# language exists to work with .Net platform that provides technologies to develop different applications. Currently u have few versions of .Net : .Net Framework and .Net 5 that includes also .Net core. WIth .Net Framework developer can create console, web and other applications that aren't crossplatform, but .Net 5 solved this problem =) And now u can easy write crossplatform applications using .Net 5. Also about differences and what to use, you can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server) article .

Comment: Your writing style has an uncanny resemblance to the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15387746/alex).  Both of you have been a member for 30 days or less.  I hope you are not making an alt profile

Comment: _".Net 5 that includes also .Net core"_ - it is incorrect to refer to .NET 5 as _".Net core"_.  .NET 5 is **.NET 5**.  **Not** .NET Framework 5.  **Not** .NET Core 5.  Also the question is _"Is `C#` Cross Platform or not?"_ not .NET Framework/Core

Comment: Ehm, c# its just instrument for writing proggrams, language cant be cross platform or not, only applications written by this language can, that`s why i wrote about .Net platform. At second, where u saw that i wrote about .Net Framework 5 or smth... anyway .Net 5 is nextgen from .Net core [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five). So .Net 5 its exactly new version of .Net Core.